# Can't access LB through cloud NAT

Tags: google-cloud-platform, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

We are running private GKE cluster over GCP.
Our services expose to the internet via nginx-ingress and TCP LB white listed in the service.yaml definition.

One of our pods is trying to access another pod through the Public LB.
(I know it's not the best practice but lets assume the app need to work only this way and we can't handle in cluster communication.)

I've also added the NAT static IP to the LB whitelist and I can see the IP as a firewall rule that connected to the GKE nodes.

What I've tried to debug the issue:

Create new instance, install nginx and allow connections only from the NAT IP by adding firewall rules. I’ve also tried to connect tcp LB to this nginx instance and have no problem to access the nginx sample page from both pod A and B.

When I’m trying to connect to the pods from other whitelisted sources I have no issue at all.

Answer (score 0):

Since kube-proxy does not follow the proxy protocol, an nginx inside the cluster would never know the real public IP it needs to block or allow.

**NGINX** ingress isn’t using services (kube-proxy) to route traffic to the pods. Instead it uses the Endpoints API. So using the proxy-protocol should work, but you also need to enable it using a **ConfigMap** .

There is a need to have bastion host to be able to ssh into your instances though.
Check if you create firewall rule that allows SSH connection.
Check if you follow the istruction from this documentation: [gke-nat](https://cloud.google.com/nat/docs/gke-example).